# What is the right term to refer to "all students" admitted in year 2014?

Tags: terminology

All students graduated in 2014 can be referred to as "class of 2014", but what term is used to refer "all students" admitted in year 2014?

Thanks!

Comment: The class  of 2018.

Comment: @Clare Thanks. I thought about this, but they do not necessarily graduate in 2018. In my program, people graduate for 4 to 7 years. In this case, is this still an appropriate term?

Comment: The 2014 intake.

Comment: Dear students, 2014 Freshman class, first term, frosh, entrant student body, they with hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either "the class of 2018"*  or "2014 matriculants."

<sup>*</sup> assuming the usual length of study to attain a degree is four years; in law school in the US it is 3 years, so for law school it would be "the class of 2017" instead.

**matriculant**

> A person who is enrolled as a student in a college or university.

from [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/matriculant)

> The predictive validity of the MCAT exam in relation to academic performance through medical school: a national cohort study of 2001–2004 matriculants.

[article in *Academic Medicine* journal](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23478635)

> The 2016 matriculants of the Chemistry and Biochemistry Ph.D.
> Programs

[City College of New York](https://www.ccny.cuny.edu/sites/default/files/CCNY%20Fall%202016%20Research%20Visit%20and%20Seminar.pdf)

For schools at which students do not all start in the same semester or term, the starting term may also be indicated--for example, *Fall 2014 matriculants*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for *[matriculants](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/matriculant)*.

> 1. A person who is enrolled as a student in a college or university.

It's not exactly as flexible as *class of*, but things like *This year's matriculants* is not uncommon, and something along the lines of *matriculants from 2014* should be generally understood

Answer (score 0):

In more general terms a group such as a 'class of [year]' is also a **cohort**. The term comes across as rather technical, however. You can also refer to a '**graduating class**' without specifying a year. There is also the phrase '**this year's incoming freshmen**' (if they are undergraduates). From the perspective of an enrolment department, e.g. in communicating internally *about* these students, the collective is termed 'this year/semester's '**intake**'.